# What did Marmee see in the man when she is volunteering?

Tags: plot-explanation, little-women

In the new *Little Women (2019)* adaptation by Greta Gerwig there is a scene where Marmee (played by Laura Dern) is volunteering. In that scene a man shows up and tells her he lost all four of his sons in the war. The camera focuses in a lot of close ups on the man's hands and on him in general. Marmee ends up giving him her scarf within the bundle of blankets and supplies she gives him.

I'm wondering if there is any significance there. Was there something in those close ups or anything that I missed? Or was she simply just being kind and offering any little bit more that she could so she threw her scarf in there? I haven't seen the original film (or any other adaptations) nor read the novel so I'm just wondering if there is a backstory or anything in the scene that I missed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have also not read the book so I can't speak for if this scene is included in there. What I took from it is that the man is homeless or at least not in a good home, the close ups on his hands were to show the fingertips turning black on the end to indicate frostbite. That is why she throws her scarf in the bag aswell she wants to provide everything she can to keep him warm.

Comment: Ah that makes total sense. I missed that his fingertips were turning black. Thanks for catching that!